# I want to know how to write data to cnosdb using encrypted communication?

Tags: cnosdb

I want to write data to cnosdb using encrypted communication, so I opened the "security.tls_config" configuration item. However, I found that using cnosdb-cli to issue SQL statements at this time will result in an error.

> error sending request for url
> (http://localhost:8902/api/v1/sql?tenant=cnosdb&db=public): connection
> closed before message completed
>
> Caused by:
> connection closed before message completed

I want to know what is the correct way to use encrypted communication.